# Align menu with the featured image

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, alignment, blogs

I came across this forum, looking for a solution to my menu problem - I can not align it properly, so that it starts always at the same level as the image. On a big screen, it goes completely crazy. My site adress is: http://anyaofficiel.com Please have a look at the screenshots: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dGfO.jpg

I am trying to achieve a similar alignment to theblondesalad.com

Does anybody have any ideas? I would highly appreciate your help!

Many thanks,
Anna

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit your `style.css` file:

Remove:
 `left: 12%;`

You have to set the left and right margin as auto.

```
.main_menu_container {
position: relative;
width: 1010px;
height: 50px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
text-align:left; }
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your answer. I just tried it out and unfortunately there is still no alignment. You can have a look at the screenshot: http://prntscr.com/4bi510. Do you know what can cause the issue?

Thank you!

Comment: did you remove left:12% from the code?

Comment: Yes, from style.css from my active child theme. Is there anything else we can try?

Comment: IT ACTUALLY WORKED! I think we had to wait a bit? THANK YOU VERY VERY MUCH!

Comment: i have checked your website. It seems to be working fine now. Isn't it what you want to achieve?

Comment: You are always welcome :)